# Date conversion in SSIS

Tags: ssis

anyone has an idea how to convert date to the format for example Monday,15-January-1990 in SSIS. 
This is what I tried converting birthdate to the example format above:

```
(DT_STR,10,1252)DAY(BirthDate) + "," 
+ (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",BirthDate) 
+ "-" + (DT_STR,15,1252)MONTH(BirthDate) 
+ "-" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yy",BirthDate)
```

The example output i get is this : `1,1-9-1965`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done so far is as far as you can get with built-in SSIS Date/Time functions.

AFAIK, SSIS does not have a built-in `WEEKFDAYNAME` or `MONTHNAME` functions. You can see that even in the Expression Builder, under Date/Time Functions, there are only the following. `MONTH` returns interger of month and `DAY` returns the actual date, not the weekday. To get the weekday, you have to pass in `"dw"` as a parameter to the `DATEPART` function (see example below). Today is Thu = weekday `#5`

[image]

That said, there are a couple of "round about ways" to achieve what you want.

#### 1. Use a scripting Task or Scripting Component to take in a date parameter and output the translated / transformed date string.

#### 2. Use a couple of variables and an expression task as detailed here => SSIS - [How To Use Expression Task To Get Day Name and Month Name In SSIS Package](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/08/ssis-how-to-use-expression-task-in-ssis.html)

[image]

[image]